# How to bind the pop up menu to a label in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to limit the area where the popup menu can be triggered

My current code allows the popup menu be triggered anywhere in the tkinter window when the user right clicks

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Right-click to display menu", width=40, height=20)
w.pack()


popup = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
popup.add_command(label="Next") # , command=next) etc...
popup.add_command(label="Previous")
popup.add_separator()
popup.add_command(label="Home")

def do_popup(event):

    try:
        popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
    finally:
        popup.grab_release()

w.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)

b = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

I want the popup menu to be triggered when the user right clicks over the label "Right-click to display menu" only

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working exactly as designed. You've created a really huge label widget (40 characters wide, 20 characters high, or roughly 350x325 pixels depending on your system font and resolution settings). So while you think you're clicking outside the label, you're not since it takes up the whole window.

To see what I mean, give your label a distinctive background color. For example:

```
w = Label(root, text="Right-click to display menu", width=40, height=20, background="pink")
```

The above results in a window that looks like the following image. Anywhere you click that is pink is part of the label, and thus will show the menu.

[image]

Comment: Why not accept and upvote the answer if it worked for you?